# Probit coefficients sum to one

Tags: categorical-data, econometrics, probit

I was recently asked the reasons and implications of constraining the coefficients of an Ordered Probit estimation to sum to one.

I sincerely never heard of it. I'm aware of the convexity property in the context of optimization, but in the case of a categorical econometric model, my best guess would be a potential need for comparing magnitudes (considering the data has been appropriately normalized?) which would sound quiet weird given the non-linearity of the model.

Could anyone share some thoughts?

Comment: Sure. I never heard of it either.